# How to re-render react-native FlatList when the screen get focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

- I'm developing a react-native app with react-navigation.
- The first screen that user sees when he opens the app has a `FlatList`component listing some products and showing their names.
- When the user clicks on any product he is navigated to the products details and he can change the name of the product.
- Then, when he navigate back to the list screen, the new name of the product should be showed in the place of the original.

I've tried to add a `extraData`prop to the `FlatList` component, but it didn't work at expected.

```js
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.washers}
    extraData={this.state} 
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.serialNumber}/>
```

The `state.washers` is an array of objects, and one of this object's property is the name.

```js
this.state.washers: Array(2):
   0: {serialNumber: "20197", model: "", name: "first washer"}
   1: {serialNumber: "201908301", model: "", name: "washer 2"}
```

When the user changes the name of a product(washer), it's saved in a text file named `{~productSerialNumber~}Name.txt`

This is the code that listen to the `screen focus` event

```js
focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', async () => {
    let washers = [];
    if (await ReactNativeFS.exists(`${ReactNativeFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/washers.json`)) {
      washers = await ReactNativeFS.readFile(`${ReactNativeFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/washers.json`, "ascii");
      washers = JSON.parse(washers);
    }
    washers.forEach(async washer => {
      const washerName = await ReactNativeFS.readFile(`${ReactNativeFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/maquinas/${washer.serialNumber}Name.txt`);
      washer.name = washerName;
    });
    this.setState({washers});
  });
}
```

Well, when I go back to the list screen, I can see that the state is changed and is updated with the new name, but it shows no changes in the `FlatList` component.

What i've seen is that when I click a product, named "name0" (for example) and change its name to "name1" (for example), then go back to the list screen, then click the same product and change its name to "name2" (for example), then the `FlatList` shows "name1" as the name

Sorry for the bad English, and thanks for any help!! <3

Comment: Could you please provide your React Native and React Navigation versions?

Comment: "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the React Navigation documentation you could try using the `withNavigationFocus` rather than the `didFocus` listener.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";

class MyScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWashers();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Check that screen is newly focused
    if (this.props.isFocused && prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
      this.updateWashers();
    }
  }

  updateWashers() {
    // put in your code to read saved data
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(MyScreen );
```

Adapted from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/function-after-focusing-screen.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've already solved this question using redux. Anyways, many thanks and sorry for not closing this thread!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your constructor.I hope it will helps you.

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
         'didFocus',
         payload => {
           // call method which you want to call 
           // call those method where your state is update
         });
     }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but it didn't worked, it keeps doing the same thing.